# error in searching a linked list

Tags: list, search, binary, linked-list

I was tasked in finding a way to search a linked list. I implemented sequential search with my code, but somehow it won't detect the first number entered to the linked list...why is that? I can find other numbers just fine.

here is my code ; https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8zpto80zw41vs4/LINKEDLIST.cpp?dl=0

also, I tried using binary search for my code, I just can't get it right...any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please reduce the code to the absolute minimum needed to demonstrate the problem and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop stops when there are no elements after the current one. When this happens, the code does not look at the current element. Change

```
while(look->next!=NULL){
```

to

```
while(look!=NULL){
```

In a linked list, there is no way to access an element by its index. Therefore, there's nothing to be gained from using binary search over linear search. Both are `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works now. as for the binary search, it doesn't matter really, it's a homework for college, the prof asked us to find a way to implement binary search for linked list...I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @Wei: Have a method to get an item by index and then implement binary search based on indices.